# Why has my attacking been disabled and why am I receiving, "You have been playing for too long and your villagers need to rest for a few minutes"?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was searching for a good base to attack this morning and I received two messages.  The first message prompted when I clicked to search for a new base, "Your attacking has been disabled" and then I was kicked from the game.

Now I am receiving a message that says, "You have been playing for too long and your villagers need to rest for a few minutes."

I spoke with a few other people I play clash of clans with and they said they could attack (not a maintenance window).

Why did I get these messages?

Comment: Not sure if I should shorten the question title... feel free to edit that.

Comment: oh yes this is a dup, **sorry about that.**  Close away!

Answer (score 1):

A [recent update](https://www.gottabemobile.com/2015/12/10/clash-of-clans-december-update-what-you-need-to-know/) rebalanced the Personal Break system, which is intended to prevent players from staying online and never being vulnerable to attack requires you to log off for a while every so often.  The exact breakdown of times was in a link from the update news, I'll see if I can find it.

The new system is a bit more forgiving of casual players, allowing you to attack from behind your Shield without forfeiting the entire Shield time, plus giving you a Guard time after your Shield breaks where you can't be attacked but can attack freely.  However, Shields are harder to earn (TH destruction doesn't automatically grant a shield now).  The time you can remain online non-stop was reduced as well, although the window between when you log off and when you can be attacked was slightly expanded.

Comment: Recent? 2013 is pretty old... oldish?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Huh.  I'd never heard of the Personal Break stuff before the new update, but apparently I just don't play enough to hit that limit.  CoC is NOT my favorite game, I just jump in, assign some upgrades and rearm some traps, and go to something else.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau there was an update yesterday that shortened the length of time you can play consecutively from 6 hours to 3 hours. then you are forced to take a personal break.

Comment: Is the downvote random, or is there an inaccuracy with the updated answer?